# Get all hash redis

Tags: redis

in redis every command want key but i want list of all hashes not a enter key (like sql (SELECT from *)) redis has a special command for this or is it not recommended?

i tried this way node.js

```
redis.keys('*', function (err, keys) {
        var val = []
        for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            redis.hgetall(keys[i], function(err, reply){
                val.push({data: reply})
            })
        }
    })
```

but return always null

Comment: It's worth noting that your SQL equivalent (`SELECT from *`) doesn't actually exist: you can select everything from a table, but not trivially list tables, which is more like what you're doing here. That said `KEYS *`, is [included as an example in the Redis documentation](https://redis.io/commands/keys), so it's not obvious why what you've tried doesn't work.

Comment: i read all hsets above command in console but when my assing any object, object always return null